# Calculations of a column based on filter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I am trying to figure out a way in which I can calculate the sum of a column in a df based on filtering a different or 2 different columns.

```
ID | Shift |Valid |Amount
B     AM      NO    23.22
E     PM      YES   231.23
D     AM      YES   443.12
R     Both    NO    43.12
T     PM      NO    111.12
```

I want to filter for Shift column like

`df[(df['shift'] == 'PM')]` and calculate the sum of the amount column

I want to try this a few times for AM, PM, Both instead of creating new dfs for each and then summing amount column.

Also if I want to also filter for the **valid** column and calculate sum of amount column without creating a new df is that possible as well?

Thanks!

Comment: df['Amount'][(df['shift'] == 'PM')].sum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Shift': ['AM', 'PM', 'AM', 'PM', 'Both'], 'Valid':['YES','NO','YES','NO','YES'],'Amount': [3, 8, 4, 5, 100]})

  Shift Valid  Amount
0    AM   YES       3
1    PM    NO       8
2    AM   YES       4
3    PM    NO       5
4  Both   YES     100
```

You can filter the data frame using the [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method:

```
df.loc[(df['Shift'] == 'AM') & (df['Valid'] == 'YES')]['Amount'].sum()
# output: 7
```

In this way the columns of the dataframe are **filtered by** `"Shift"` and `"Valid"` and the values ​​of `"Amount"` are added up

Alternatively, you can use the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) command and get all the results in one go:

```
df.groupby(['Valid','Shift'])['Amount'].sum()

Valid  Shift
NO     PM        13
YES    AM         7
       Both     100
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

In this way all the columns of the dataframe are **grouped by** `"Shift"` and `"Valid"` and the values ​​of `"Amount"` are added together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataFrame.Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) 
and use one or more columns to form the groups:

```
shift_sum=df.groupby('Shift')['Amount'].sum()
print(shift_sum)

Shift
AM      466.34
Both     43.12
PM      342.35
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

this way you get the sum for `AM`, `PM` and `Both` directly.

After if you want you can select only 'AM' sum value:

```
shift_sum['PM']

342.25
```

the same could you use to add based on `valid`

```
df.groupby('Valid')['Amount'].sum()

Valid
NO     177.46
YES    674.35
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

Even you could combinate both:

```
df.groupby(['Valid','Shift'])['Amount'].sum()
Valid  Shift
NO     AM        23.22
       Both      43.12
       PM       111.12
YES    AM       443.12
       PM       231.23
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df['shift'] == 'PM']['Amount'].sum()
```